# I can't deactivate wired ens33 on nmtui

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, dns, networkmanager, vmware

[image]

I tried to Deactivate the cable ens33 in nmtui, and I get an error message NetworkManager TUI

"Could not activate connection: Connection 'ens33' is not available on device ens33 because device is strictly unmanaged"

I've been looking for a solution to all forums on Google, but I can't solve this problem

Os: centos7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the status of network interface because is set to `unmanaged` (`managed=false`). Use `nmcli -p device` to check it.

Edit the global configuration file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` as follows:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Check it through `nmcli`:

```
nmcli -p device
```

The you will be able to activate/desactivate the network.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method depending on your config, a slight twist on what GAD3R mentioned.

If you have config files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts (ie: */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens7*), then what worked for me was to include `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` in those files, and then restart the network manager service with `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Once these steps were complete, I was able to activate/deactivate my previously created connection profiles (IE: `nmcli con up route-ens8`)

You can now check the status of said device(s) with `nmcli device`, and they should show *connected* instead of *unmanaged*:

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
ens4    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1
ens6    ethernet  connected  System ens6
ens7    ethernet  connected  route-ens7
ens8    ethernet  connected  route-ens8
ens5    ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

OS: I was using RHEL 8 in this case.